# Complex numbers - A mathematical model has been proposed for the velocity v of a projectile, based on its position x

Tags: complex-numbers

A mathematical model has been proposed for the velocity v of a projectile, based on its position x, and is given by the relationship:

$$\ln(y) = \gamma \ \ln(x)$$

Find the value of γ (gamma), given that
$ \ y \   = \ {7}e^{j \frac{\pi}{ 5 } } \ , $ when $ \  x \ = \ {7}e^{ \ 8 \  - \ j \frac{\pi}{ 3 }} $

Give your answer in polar form, with the angle in degrees.

My attempt so far:

$$y= {7}e^{j \frac{\pi}{{5}} }  = {7}e^{j·{0.63}}$$

ln(7) = 1.95

1.95+j·0.63

$$x = {7}e^{ {8} - j \frac{\pi}{{3}}} =  {7}e^{ {8} - j·1.05}$$

ln(7) = 1.95

1.95+8- j·1.05

= 9.95 - j·1.05

So i have these calculations which i think i am on the right path and correct.

So $$ 1.95+j·0.63 =  \gamma · ( 9.95-j·1.05) $$

This is where i am stuck. How do i find the value of gamma?

Also are my calulations and method correct this far?

Answer (score 1):

Your work looks fine up to the point where you stopped. Is the issue that you are not familiar with division of complex numbers?

You have
$$ \gamma \ \ = \ \ \frac{\ln 7 \ + \ j·\frac{\pi}{5}}{(\ln 7 \ + \ 8) \ - \ j·\frac{\pi}{3}} \ \ , $$

which, as a ratio of complex numbers, will likely be a complex number itself.  You then need to multiply the numerator and denominator of the ratio by the "complex conjugate" of the denominator:  this will produce a real number in the denominator and will aid in whatever simplification may follow.
$$ \gamma \ \ = \ \ \frac{\ln 7 \ + \ j·\frac{\pi}{5}}{(\ln 7 \ + \ 8) \ - \ j·\frac{\pi}{3}} \ · \ \frac{(\ln 7 \ + \ 8) \ + \ j·\frac{\pi}{3}}{(\ln 7 \ + \ 8) \ + \ j·\frac{\pi}{3}}  $$

$$ = \ \ \frac{(\ln 7)·(\ln 7 \ + \ 8) \ + \ (j·\frac{\pi}{5})   ·(j·\frac{\pi}{3}) \ + \  (\ln 7)·(j·\frac{\pi}{3}) \ + \ (\ln 7 \ + \ 8)·( j·\frac{\pi}{5})}{(\ln 7 \ + \ 8)^2 \ - \ j^2·\left(\frac{\pi}{3} \right)^2}  $$
$$ = \ \ \frac{(\ln 7)·(\ln 7 \ + \ 8) \ - \ (\frac{\pi}{5}·\frac{\pi}{3}) \ \ + \ \  j· [ \ (\ln 7)· \frac{\pi}{3}  \ + \ (\ln 7 \ + \ 8)· \frac{\pi}{5} \ ]}{(\ln 7 \ + \ 8)^2 \ + \ \left(\frac{\pi}{3} \right)^2} \ \ , $$
this being the *exact* expression for $ \ \gamma \ \ . $

To judge from what you have written, it appears that an approximation is satisfactory:
$$ \gamma \ \ \approx \ \ \frac{19.354 \ - \ 0.658 \ \ + \ \  j· ( \ 2.038  \ + \ 6.249 \ )}{98.921 \ + \ 1.097} \ \ \approx \ \ \frac{18.696}{100.018} \ + \ j·\frac{8.287}{100.018} $$ $$ \approx \ \ 0.187 \ + \ j·0.083 \ \ . $$

For the polar form, the modulus is then $ \ r \ \approx \ \sqrt{0.187^2 \ + \ 0.083^2} \ \approx \ 0.205 \ \ .  $  Since both the real and imaginary parts are positive, the angle is in the first quadrant and can be found from
$$ \tan \theta \ \ = \ \ \frac{0.083}{0.187} \ \ \approx \ \ 0.444 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \theta \ \ \approx \ \ 23.93º \ \ . $$
(In exponential form, we would have $ \ \gamma \ \approx \ 0.205·e^{j·0.418} \ \ , $ since the angle in the exponent  needs to be given in radians.)